# не срабатывает запрос

Tags: mysql, база-данных

прошу вашей помощи, в mysql совсем новичок. есть две таблицы 
student с полями id_st, id_gr1, name и group с полями id_gr, name_gr. нужно посчитать и вывести количество студентов в каждой группе. в моем запросе выводит только один результат

SELECT gr.`name_gr` , count( st.`id_gr1` ) AS sd
   FROM gr
   JOIN st ON st.id_gr1 = gr.id_gr

Comment: Хм, может  
 SELECT Count(*) AS sd FROM student INNER JOIN group on id_gr1=id_gr

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT gr.name_gr , count( st.id_gr1 ) AS sd FROM gr JOIN st ON st.id_gr1 = gr.id_gr GROUP BY gr.name_gr
```